# Plot confidence interval, points and line

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I know there's a lot of question about this topic, but i can't find the answer i need. Years ago i used R, now i can't remember anything, but i'm sure is possible to draw a chart like this, with confidence intervals for every single points, and the main line between points (like in the screenshot). I already have all datas i need, pre calculated with spreadsheet. A simple example:

- points value (average of previous values): 4 (at 10 meters),5 (at 20 meters),6 (at 30 meters)
- confidence interval: 0.2 (for value 4), 0.5 (for value 5), 0.9 (for value 6)

I need the syntax to draw a chart like this:[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ggplot2` for easy and quick plotting.

```
data <- data.frame(distance = c(10, 20, 30),
                   value    = c(4, 5, 6),
                   CI       = c(0.2, 0.5, 0.9))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(distance, value)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = value - CI, ymax = value + CI)) +
    labs(x = "DISTANCE",
         y = "VALUES",
         title = "MY TITLE") +
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! This is exactly what i need.

Comment: @Johannes happy to help

Comment: Excuse me, another quick question: if I want insert others lines? for example:

values2=c(6,7,8),
CI2=c(0.2, 0.11. 0.17)

I read some similar questions here on stackoverflow, but i can't figure out how to do it in this case. I thinks i have to use "group" commands in ggplot..thanks

Comment: @Johannes I would create two different tables with additional column (type = "A" in one and type = "B" in another one). Then I would `rbind` them. And set color in `aes(color = type)`